# Positioning a DOM element on top of others

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

Here is the prototype I am working on [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/iqagov/9/edit).

When mouse hover for 1 sec on any of text input fields, I made a pop-up box to display to a hovered element. Now, how can I make the pop-up box sit on top of others so it doesn't affect positioning of other elements? like a tooltip?

It seems that I can use `position()` of jQuery UI but I am not very clear how I can apply this for my specific needs.

Comment: You would use the jQuery UI positioning, and position the div relative to the textbox when it is shown. You'll probably also need to use `position:absolute` on your popup, not sure if `position()` does that for you.

Comment: You can set the `position:absolute` for that element and then set a `z-index`

Answer (score 1):

You can set the css-value `position` to `absolute` for the tooltip element.
This way, it is removed from the ordinary content flow and put in a layer on top.

If you want it attached to its container element, then set `position: relative` for that.